# How to make autocompleting textbox in VB6?

Tags: vb6, textbox, autocomplete

I want to have an auto-completing textbox like the one in the image below:
[image]

This screenshot is from an accounting software. Whenever the user focuses on a textbox and starts typing something, the suggestions just pop up under the control (as seen in the image under the Purc type textbox). This auto-suggest functionality even works in the cells of the grid shown in the picture. Moreover, the fields in which this auto-suggest is enabled allow only values from the auto-suggest list to be filled up and nothing else.

I want to emulate similar functionality in my app in VB6. Any ideas on how to implement auto-completing textbox in VB6?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the AutoComplete Text Box at [FreeVBCode.com](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=636).

Another option is at [VBNet](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/textapi/shautocomplete.htm).  The article shows how to use shlwapi.dll api.

Comment: hey thanks for replying so quickly. The first solution didn't work on my pc. haven't tested the second yet.

Answer (score 1):

What I've typically done is do what is included in the project link by C-Pound Guru. Take a TextBox and as the user types into the field have a ListBox fill with results matching the text. The ListBox would by default be hidden but will be made visible when text is entered into the field. When the ListBox is clicked then simply update the TextBox with the ListBox's selected item text then hide the ListBox control again. A quite simple routine to complete.

Comment: hey thanks for the insight,and yes its simple and yet effective solution to what i want to do but how do i make it work in the datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

VBAccelerator is an excellent site for VB6 tips - try their [AutoComplete](http://vbaccelerator.com/article.asp?id=1411) sample

Comment: hey thanks for the link.... it's  very good link, but will it work in vb6... also how do i make it work in a datagrid...

Comment: @Amit Doh! I linked to the VB.Net sample instead of the VB6 one. I've edited it now to link to the VB6 one instead.